# iframe.document.body.scrollHeight is double the correct value

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

`<iframe name="asdf" id="asdf" onload="change_height(this)" src="asdf.jsp" width="250" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

```
        function change_height(iframe) {
            if (document.all) {
                // IE.
                ieheight = iframe.document.body.scrollHeight;
                iframe.style.height = ieheight;
            } else {
                // Firefox.
                ffheight= iframe.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight;
                iframe.style.height = ffheight+ 'px';

            }
        }
```

ieheight is twice the actual height when this runs in IE7; haven't tested on IE6.  It's the same value if I use *scrollHeight* or *offsetHeight*.

It's the correct height in Firefox.

Before I patch this by just dividing the IE value /2, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`document.body` represents the viewport when IE is running in Quirks Mode. If the document inside your iframe is in Quirks, the `scrollHeight` of the `body` will be equal to the height of its viewport, ie. the default height of the iframe.

If you really needed to get the document-height in Quirks Mode you would have to add an extra wrapper div to measure. A much better fix is to make sure all your documents use a Standards Mode doctype. You shouldn't be authoring anything with Quirks Mode in this decade.

Also, you shouldn't use `document.all` for IE sniffing (this may go wrong for other browsers that support it), you shouldn't use `iframe.document` (it's non-standard and not even documented by MSDN), and you should always add `'px'` units (IE can cope with it fine and you need it in Standards Mode).

```
function change_height(iframe) {
    var doc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframe.style.height= doc.body.offsetHeight+'px';
}
```

Comment: In IE7, that's just giving me the pre-existing height of the window, not the size of its contents.  Help?  :-)

Comment: As I said, that's what will happen in Quirks Mode. In Standards Mode, `body` is really the height of the content in the `<body>` element. Don't use Quirks Mode. It's not nice.

Comment: I don't have full control of the content in the iframe, it's someone in another group, I'll have to get them to help me.  That aside, Thank You!

Comment: If anyone's followed this so far, the following link helped clear up which DOCTYPE headers trigger quirks mode, and which don't: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: Also, note that in IE7, `iframe.document.scrollHeight` can give a different number than `iframe.contentWindow.document.scrollHeight`.  I think it's the same with the other values.  Using `contentWindow` worked best for me.

Comment: @Nelson: What it is: there is a property `document` on every element node in IE. It is an undocumented synonym for the standard DOM `ownerDocument` property on `Node`. So `iframe.document===document`—the parent document, not the child iframe document. So you'd be getting the height of the parent window not the child iframe (assuming you actually did `iframe.document.documentElement.scrollHeight`; there is no `document.scrollHeight` property).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
function change_height(iframe) {
    var doc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframe.style.height= doc.body.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

also i modify it's code to use by jquery

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ZIAutoHeight = function() {
        var t = this, doc = 'contentDocument' in t[0]? t[0].contentDocument : t[0].contentWindow.document;
        t.css('height', doc.body.scrollHeight+'px');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage `$('iframe').ZIAutoHeight();` hope that's help