# get height of source page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, height

Using JS or jquery I need to get the height of the html page that is the `src` of an iframe. This is what I have and it is not returning a value.

```
var iFrameID = document.getElementById('myframe');
iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Yes, I am trying to set the height of my iframe this way (the common problem of resizing the iframe based on content). I just know that the `iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` is not giving me a height value for the source page. This problem does not happen in Firefox.

EDIT: This is for offline use. I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Firefox correctly returns a value for `iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight`. Chrome is not returning a value.

Comment: I also tried `$('iframe').contents().find('body').height()`, but it returns 'null'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get height of iframe content when loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846132/jquery-get-height-of-iframe-content-when-loaded)

Comment: I have spent way too much time trying to implement the answer on that page, but to no avail, which is why I posted a new question.