# different values for scrollHeight on different devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have 2 devices:
First (Flat screen with docking station): screen resolution: **1600 x 1200px**
Second (Laptop): screen resolution: **1366 x 768px**

Now I have a website with content (within an iframe). I determine the content height with the following code:

```
document.getElementById('id_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
```

On the **first device** I have got an height of **2026px**. However on the **second one** I just have **870px**. The problem is that I need the correct content height because I would like to enlarge the iframe height so that I do not get a second scrollbar at the iframe.

Does anyone have an idea? What could be wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**

The correct height is 2026px;

**Additional information**

I tried a lower resolution (1280 x 768px) on the first device and I get the same effect as on the laptop! So I can say that the problem is depending to the screen resolution.

---

Might this be the answer also to my question? [scrollHeight gives incorrect value when height property is provided in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602914/scrollheight-gives-incorrect-value-when-height-property-is-provided-in-css)

Comment: Probably you have images (without a set height) or other content inside, that is not loaded at the time you check `scrollHeight`. You should check the height at the `onload` of the iframe to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Surely given the different resolutions the wrapping etc of the elements contained within the iframe will cause different screens to render them in different configurations making their rendered heights different?

Comment: @t.niese: Thanks for advice. However I do the check of the height at the onload of the iframe and wait additionally 0.5 sec for loading images. I tested it also with 5 sec. So I am sure that the page is completely loaded when I determine the height.

Comment: @zuluk an additional info that would be helpful is, if the `iframe` has an initial fixe size and in which browser you see that behavior.

Comment: @t.niese: There is an initial fixed height of 2000px for the iframe. The browser is IE 9.0.8.

Comment: @zuluk this is probably not the same problem but it could be the same solution [Answer to: iframe.document.body.scrollHeight is double the correct value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684969/1960455). You should always check that you create your pages in standard mode (i would suggest to use the doc type `<!doctype html>` to avoid many problems in IE)

Comment: @t.niese: I have edited my question. The fact is, that the height of 2026px is the correct height. So the correct value is not doubled. I tried the metatag mentioned behind your posted link but it does not matter.

Comment: @zuluk But did you check if the `offsetHeight` gives you the correct height on both devices?

Comment: @t.niese Now I have counted the pixels of the content height on the second device: the **content is 1760 px** high. So on the second device the `offsetHeight` does not give me the correct height.

Comment: I have updated my question above with **additional information**...

Comment: the best way to get the most reliable information is using jquery